# Authenticating against SharePoint online in Powershell without using user name and password

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

Is it possible to use the context of the person whoever is running the PowerShell and get the list items from SharePoint online?

I am trying not to have the `Get-Credential` login prompt or having the User name password in some file or in the PowerShell file/Windows Credentials Manager

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below PowerShell code:

```
$ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)

$Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 

$ctx.Credentials = $Credentials; 

$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Note :

- The logged in user must have appropriate permissions to SharePoint to do the task.
- The account should not have MFA enabled.

Reference URL:

[Instantiate SharePoint Client Context using current user credentials in PowerShell](https://www.google.com/amp/s/reshmeeauckloo.wordpress.com/2016/11/02/instantiate-sharepoint-client-context-using-current-user-credentials-in-powershell/amp/)

**How to fix the "403 error, it says Exception calling ExecuteQuery with 0 arguments" from PowerShell to SharePoint Online connection?**

In order to fix the 403 error, we need need to follow the below steps:

1. Open PowerShell and type “notepad $profile”
2. Ensure the below code is present.
3. NOTE – CSOM must load before SOM (Server Object Model) for requests to execute correctly.   Workaround for an internal Microsoft naming overlap.  Both are probably using the same object somewhere. Loading **CSOM** first allows **CSOM** to reserve the namespace first.

Example:

```
#CSOM first
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null

#SOM
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Reference:

[FIXED – 403 ExecuteQuery CSOM from a SharePoint Serve](https://www.spjeff.com/2016/08/07/fixed-403-executequery-csom-sharepoint-server/)

Comment: I tried this and this gives me 403 error, it says Exception calling ExecuteQuery with 0 arguments

Comment: just a note, we login using Domain\UserName and SP Online has permissions given to UserName@Domain.com

Comment: Check the updated answer - it might help you to fix the 403 error.